# Input Arguement

Tags: python, input, arguments, command

im trying to make an input arguement on Python, and want to ask if its possible and how to do it.

So i want to make something like this

```py
choice = input("=> ")
```

So i want to make something similar to command line argument, so i want to make user do something like this

```
>> => arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Then it will be saved as a variable

```py
var1 = arg1
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: what do you actually want to do?  What should the program do with arg2 and arg3?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
arg1, arg2, arg3 = input("=> ").split()
print('arg1 ', arg1)
print('arg2 ', arg2)
print('arg3 ', arg3)
```

output

```
=> val1 val2 val3
arg1  val1
arg2  val2
arg3  val3
```